# Is it possible to upgrade 16GB ram for any corei5, 5th Gen Laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, ramdisk, intel-core-i5

I am little bit confuse about upgrading my RAM for laptop.

I just want to extend RAM to 12GB by adding another 8GB in [this laptop](http://www.vijaysales.com/HP-15-AC033TX-Laptop-Core-i5-5200U-4GB-RAM-1TB-HDD-15-6-39-6-cm-2GB-Graphics-Win-8-1/2514). Is it possible?

If yes, then why everywhere it is mentioned that **EXPANDABLE RAM : 8 GB** ?

Is there any disadvantages?

Comment: Please provide us the specification page from HP's website.  The maintenance manual will provide the information you need to determine your capability to add more memory.  I am going to guess it only has a single slot, and if it has two, then its not suggest to have two difference sizes installed.

Comment: Check the official HP documentation http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-15-Notebook-PC-series/7771404/model/8326100/document/c00820047/. It's possible that your mainboard does not feature more than 2/4GB per slot.

Comment: [HP Notebook 15-ac033tx Product Specifications](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04731203)

Comment: "4 GB DDR3L-1600 SDRAM (1 x 4 GB)" - This would indicate you have a single module, have no empty slot, so running 12GB given your hardware is not possible.

Comment: @Ramhound, if this is the case, according to you for [HP Pavilion 15-ab032tx](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC-series/7771366/model/7919380/document/c04700593/) also not possible to extend RAM?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia - Check the manual.

Comment: @Ramhound, I think "4 GB DDR3L-1600 SDRAM (1 x 4 GB)" indicates that 1 slot is full with 4GB.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia - Check the service manual to confirm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This laptop has 2 SO-DIMM slots.
One of them has a 4GB module fitted in the factory. The other is empty.
The maximum RAM size, for each slot, is 8 GB.

So you can add a 8 GB module for a total of 12 GB.
And you can replace the current 4GB module with a 8 GB module giving you 16 GB total.

Having 2 identical RAM modules allows use of them in dual-channel mode which is marginally faster (usually not more than 3%-5%) than single-channel.
Having more RAM is usually much more beneficial to Windows/applications than the small speed benefit of dual-channel versus single-channel, so I would not worry about using a mixed RAM configuration.

**Please note:** Most HP laptops are quite picky and will  NOT work if the RAM isn't certified. Check the HP web-site for compatible RAM modules before you buy.

Comment: Hi @Tonny, Thanks, but I am not getting any part of your answer start from **Having 2 identica :( Can you please explain it in little bit in easy lang?

Comment: do you mean 8GB + 4GB is not recommended?

Comment: Also, what is certified RAM ?

Comment: I think you are going to have to do more research yourself. :)

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia 8+4 will work fine. 4+4 or 8+8 will give marginally faster speed of the RAM. Hardly noticeable in real life. The benefit gained from having 4+8 instead of 4+4 due to more RAM is much more noticeable. So buy what you can afford. Certified RAM just means RAM that is certified and approved for use in this laptop by HP itself.

Comment: @Tonny Thanks, make sense :) How can I come to know which RAM is certified with HP? Is there any list available? Link?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia List can be found on the HP support web-site. Each model laptop/desktop has it's own list.

Comment: @Tonny, thanks but I am not able to find that list, can you please help me to find out that? My model is **`HP Notebook 15-ac026tx`**

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia Seems HP recently changed their policy. Seems that any SO-DIMM of the correct spec (DDR3L-1600Mhz) should work. Best thing to do is go to the Kingston or Crucial web-site and use the wizard to select the proper RAM for your system (HP M9V02PA or 15-ac026tx, both are the same model). Both vendors have their own compatibility lists which are reliable and HP even recommends to use them. Obviously: You don't have to buy from these online shops. Just use them to figure out the correct RAM type. Whatever you buy, just make sure you can return it if the laptop doesn't like it.